# Calling PySP Progressive Hedging from Python script

Tags: python, pyomo

chapter 18.1 of Pyomo documentation (https://software.sandia.gov/downloads/pub/pyomo/PyomoOnlineDocs.html#_pyomo_overview)presents the way of using Python scripts for Pyomo. However, I didn't quite understand if it's possible to use PySP Progressive Hedging in the same way.
I want to define a model within a Python script and solve it there using PySP Progressive Hedging with Gurobi as a solver. My question is, how can I call PySP PH from Python script? The only way I found is to call runph with parameters from command line.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you find the solution for this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is it right to ask if your question is solving Progressive Hedging with solver Gurobi?

If so, I think solving the PH by solvering gurobi is done by adding "--solver = gurobi" to the command window.

For example, you may type in command window 
[runph --model-directory="filename.py" --solver=gurobi](or Gurobi, I'm sorry that I have never use this solver)